# How to use Teleporters in Terraria

Tags: terraria

How do you use teleporters in terraria? I do not know how and it is confusing. The school blocks the wiki, so I need a guide here.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20170401024758/http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Teleporter

Answer (score 2):

To wire two teleporters together, I use levers, but you put some sort of trigger above the teleporter. Then wire the teleporter and the trigger to your other teleporter, and most of the time you'll need another trigger in the same wire path as the two teleporters and the first trigger, if you want to be able to go back. If you want to make a system going all the way across the map, with several stops along the way, you'll need to make breaks in the wire path at every teleporter stop.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've also noticed that if you put pressure plates on there, it's handy for instant teleporting.

Answer (score 1):

To use a teleporter, you first need to buy 2 of them. then you put the 2 where you want to travel to and from. then put a switch or lever on top of them and hook them up with wire. Make sure it doesn't touch the same color wire and it touches the yellow thing in the middle of the teleporter and the switch/lever. Then flip the switch/lever to teleport to the desired area!